# Linux process holding deleted file space

Tags: linux, file-descriptor, lsof

I have a process which is accessing a file. When I delete the file from the file system the space is not freed. when I do `lsof | grep deleted` I can see the process is holding the deleted file.

I tried to kill the process through `kill -9 <pid>` my application rebooted and still the space is not recovered back.

After reboot if I try `lsof | grep deleted` I cannot see any process holding the deleted file. But the free space is not reflected properly.

Is there any way to recover the space of a deleted file if the process no longer available or application rebooted?

Comment: This solution might help you
[1]: https://superuser.com/questions/738690/deleting-files-but-disk-space-is-still-full

Comment: Even after the process is killed the space is not recovered back